# test Nginx config file using the real nginx.conf

Tags: nginx, automated-tests, nginx-location

Is there a way to test Nginx config file using the real nginx conf and not define the config in the test file, to avoid duplicated changes in new features?

Thanks,
Nir

Comment: The real and test environments are kept separate, you should make a copy of real environment and put that in test file. Just make sure that any changes in real are reflected back in the test one

Comment: @NitinSingh, Thanks!